# Connect to OpenVPN on Ubuntu Server from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ubuntu, openvpn

I am on my Windows 7 laptop and want to connect to my home network and browse to \\192.168.1.10.

I have a Ubuntu Server running on my home network on 192.168.1.11.

So far I have done this on my Ubuntu Server:

```
apt-get install openvpn
```

What do I need to do now to allow my Windows 7 laptop to connect to the OpenVPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may configure your OpenVPN server, and you have to generate your CA certificate and the server.key file. Please find [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/openvpn-server-on-centos-5.2) a full tuto about installing openvpn on a CentOS, the configuration step is the same for any linux OS.
After, take a look to the [windows Gui OpenVPN.](http://openvpn.se/)